# blur/focusout event on <tr>: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a table in one of my component in my Angular4 application, and I'm adding styles to the table rows  when the user clicks on any of the table row (adding a css highlight color). Now, I want to remove the highlight color when the user clicks anywhere else other than that row.
I tried doing the following:

```
<tr (blur)="removeStyles()">
```

and

```
<tr (focusout)="removeStyles()">
```

ut none of the above are triggering the method removeStyles. Has anybody tried binding any of the above or similar event to a  before?

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/arkon/ng-click-outside ?

Comment: not relevant to question, but why cant you do that using css

Comment: @Skeptor, I can add a hover state with CSS but how can I add a blur/focusout state?

Comment: @Aiguo did you find a workaround?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `tabindex` to your `<tr>`s. Focus events will only fire when the element's `tabindex` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside in the project.
This should work in your case.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a solution that I can code because I don't want to create dependencies for something trivial.